# ember-data: How to POST properly

Tags: javascript, rest, ember.js, ember-data

I've set up an ember.js client with ember-data as persistance handler.
Fetching all records from the DB works fine with this code:

**router.js**

```
App.ProjectsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function() {
        return this.store.find('project');
    }
});
```

But adding a new record doesn't work correctly with this code. It's only added to the model and not persisted.

**index.html (example)**

```
{{input type="text" id="newTitle" value=Title}}
<button class="small" {{action 'createProject'}}><i class="icon-plus-sign"></i></button>
```

**Controller.js**

```
App.ProjectsController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
    actions: {
        createProject: function () {
            var project = this.store.createRecord('project', {
                project_number: this.get('newProject_number'),
                title: this.get('newTitle'),
                client: this.get('newClient'),
                comment: this.get('newComment'),
                xmlfile: this.get('newXmlfile')
            });
            this.set('newProject_number', '');
            this.set('newTitle', '');
            this.set('newClient', '');
            this.set('newComment', '');
            project.save();
        }
    }
});
```

**models.js**

```
App.Project = DS.Model.extend({
    title: DS.attr('string'),
    client: DS.attr('string'),
    comment: DS.attr('string'),
    project_number: DS.attr('string'),  
});
```

**app.js**

```
window.App = Ember.Application.create();

App.store = DS.Store.extend({
    adapter: DS.RESTAdapter,
});

DS.RESTAdapter.reopen({
  namespace: 'api/index.php',
  headers: {
      "API_KEY": "secret key",
      "ANOTHER_HEADER": "Some header value"
    }
});
```

**Framework versions**

```
Ember : 1.2.0; 
Ember Data : 1.0.0-beta.5+canary.e120006;
Handlebars : 1.1.2; 
jQuery : 2.0.3;
```

What have I missed to configure? There's no error in the console however.
REST-Api works well with curl.

Comment: What version of ED are you using?  that notation is old, guessing I'd say you are using an old version that required commit to be called

Comment: Sorry, I've missed that:
`code`
Ember      : 1.2.0;
Ember Data : 1.0.0-beta.5+canary.e120006;
Handlebars : 1.1.2;
jQuery     : 2.0.3; 
`code`

Comment: When you say persisted you're saying no network POST, right?  Looking in the network tab, nothing is sent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the structure of the JSON "POST"ed towards the API:

**Sent:**

```
{project: {client: "test",comment: "test",project_number: "test",title: "test"}}
```

**Expected by API-Backend:**

```
{client: "test",comment: "test",project_number: "test",title: "test"}
```

I wonder where I could have found the information how ember-data build it's requests. (For further development)

Comment: There is some information on the expected JSON format here: http://emberjs.com/guides/models/the-rest-adapter/